# Merging dataframes iteratively with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to merge two dataframes in pandas, using read_csv. But one of my dataframes (in this example `d1`) is too big for my computer to handle, so I'm using the `iterator` argument in `read_csv`.

Let's say I have two dataframes

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    "col2": [5,4,3,2,5,43,2,5,6],
    "col3": [10,10,10,10,10,4,10,10,10]}, 
    index=["paul", "peter", "lauren", "dave", "bill", "steve", "old-man", "bob", "tim"])

d2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "yes/no": [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]}, 
    index=["paul", "peter", "lauren", "dave", "bill", "steve", "old-man", "bob", "tim"])
```

I need to merge them so that each row captures all data for each person, so the equivalent of doing:

```
pd.concat((d1,d2), axis=1,join="outer")
```

but since I can't fit d1 into memory, I've been using `read_csv` (I'm using  `read_csv` because I already processed a huge file and saved it into .csv format, so imagine my dataframe d1 is contained in the file `test.csv`).

```
itera = pd.read_csv("test.csv",index_col="index",iterator=True,chunksize=2)
```

But when I do

```
for i in itera:
    d2 = pd.concat((d2,i), axis=1,join="outer")
```

my output is the first dataframe appended by the second dataframe.

My output looks like this:

```
        col1  col2  col3   yes/no
one     NaN   NaN   NaN     1.0
two     NaN   NaN   NaN     0.0
three   NaN   NaN   NaN     1.0
four    NaN   NaN   NaN     0.0
five    NaN   NaN   NaN     1.0
six     NaN   NaN   NaN     1.0
seven   NaN   NaN   NaN     1.0
eight   NaN   NaN   NaN     0.0
nine    NaN   NaN   NaN     0.0
one     1.0   5.0  10.0     NaN
two     2.0   4.0  10.0     NaN
three   3.0   3.0  10.0     NaN
four    4.0   2.0  10.0     NaN
five    5.0   5.0  10.0     NaN
six     6.0  43.0   4.0     NaN
seven   7.0   2.0  10.0     NaN
eight   8.0   5.0  10.0     NaN
nine    9.0   6.0  10.0     NaN
```

Hope my question makes sense :)

Comment: Fast answer: try to use Dask library, it can handle big dataframes which can't fit into memory: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/

Comment: *my output is the first dataframe appended by the second dataframe*...what did you want?

Comment: Try a nested concat: `pd.concat([d1, pd.concat(itera, ignore_index=True)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [combine first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns) method.  It basically updates `df1` with values from the each chunk in the `read_csv` iterator.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    "col2": [5,4,3,2,5,43,2,5,6],
    "col3": [10,10,10,10,10,4,10,10,10]}, 
    index=["paul", "peter", "lauren", "dave", "bill", "steve", "old-man", "bob", "tim"])


#d2 converted to string tho use with pd.read_csv
d2 =  StringIO("""y/n col5
paul 1 
peter 0 
lauren 1 
dave 0 
bill 1 
steve 1
old-man 1
bob 0
tim 0
""")

#For each chunk update d1 with data
for chunk in pd.read_csv(d2, sep = ' ',iterator=True,chunksize=1):
    d1 = d1.combine_first(chunk[['y/n']])
#Number formatting
d1['y/n'] = d1['y/n'].astype(int)
```

Which returns `d1` looking like:

```
         col1  col2  col3  y/n
bill        5     5    10    1
bob         8     5    10    0
dave        4     2    10    0
lauren      3     3    10    1
old-man     7     2    10    1
paul        1     5    10    1
peter       2     4    10    0
steve       6    43     4    1
tim         9     6    10    0
```

Comment: Marked as the answer, as it gives me the output I asked for. But when I try it on the huge it is taking the union of those two datasets making my d2 become at least an order of magnitude bigger (It seems like it is becoming twice as big, minus the values it can find in the chunk, each iteration). So even though it is not what I wanted, it is what I asked for; thanks, I guess I'm a little closer to my goal now.

Comment: `d1` is bigger than `d2`? Last time I read your question I thought the opposite.

Comment: Okay, I've just clarified the post for future reference; but yes it is.